# Using bash read command to retrieve multiple words

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script and i have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo Enter some text
read tweet
t update  $tweet
```

I have sferik `t` installed to tweet using the `t update` command and i want to pass multiple words into the `$tweet` variable however i am reciving this message.

```
ERROR: "t update" was called with arguments ["sdfs", "sdfsdf"]
Usage: "t update [MESSAGE]"
```

Comment: The question isn't about `read`, it's about quoting; and any basic Bash intro will explain this in the first sentence of the section about quoting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the variable so it's passed as a single argument to `t`:

```
t update "$tweet"
```

In general, **always** quote your variables unless you know *exactly* why you should not.

Comment: i am now getting this error /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/parser/arguments.rb:12:in `block in split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Comment: What is your locale? `env | grep ^LC; echo $LANG`